# Creating line segments at point coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, polyline-creation, angles

I have a point vector layer with `"angle"` field. How can I create line segments at these points with certain length and angle?

I did this with style options but I need this physically as lines vector layer:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One possible tool is ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) in the `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry` (search in the Processing Toolbox <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

[image]

A **Geometry expression** to create lines (*length= 100 m*) is as below:

```
make_line(project($geometry, 50, radians("angle")), project($geometry, 50, radians("angle"+180)))
```

- `project($geometry, 50, radians("angle"))` part creates a new point by moving your points to "angle" direction by 50 meters.
- `project($geometry, 50, radians("angle"+180))` creates another point to the oposite direction.
- `make_line()` ties the above two points, so the total line length is 100 meters.
- `project()` function assumes that your "angle" is measured clockwise from north, so this expression may require edits depending on how your "angle" field is made.

[image]

NB. Do not forget saving created `Modified geometry` layer as a new dataset, otherwise it will be lost when you finish QGIS session.

Answer (score 7):

I put an example of solving the same task with a PyQGIS (3.2) standalone application.

Below is the Python code:

```py
import sys
import math
from qgis.core import (QgsPointXY,
                       QgsApplication,
                       QgsVectorLayer,
                       QgsFeature,
                       QgsGeometry)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


def main():
    print('Start program')

    qgis_prefix_path = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis'
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix_path, True)

    QgsApplication.initQgis()

    point_path = 'd:/Users/Bogomolov/Qgis/Test_prj/point.shp'
    line_path = 'd:/Users/Bogomolov/Qgis/Test_prj/lines.shp'
    point_layer = QgsVectorLayer(point_path, "pointlayer", "ogr")
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(line_path, "linelayer", "ogr")


    for feature in point_layer.getFeatures():
        geom: QgsGeometry = feature.geometry()
        pnt: QgsPointXY = geom.asPoint()
        length = feature['distance']
        bearing = feature['bearing']
        id = feature['id']
        print('id=', id)
        pnt0 = direct_geodetic_task(pnt, length / 2, bearing + 180)
        pnt1 = direct_geodetic_task(pnt, length / 2, bearing)
        points = []
        points.append(pnt0)
        points.append(pnt1)
        fields = layer.dataProvider().fields()
        feature = QgsFeature()
        feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(points))
        feature.setFields(fields)
        feature.setAttribute('id', id)
        layer.dataProvider().addFeature(feature)

    # layer.commitChanges()

    QgsApplication.exitQgis()

def direct_geodetic_task(pnt, dist, bear):
    if bear > 360.0:
        bear = bear - 360
    if bear < 0:
        bear = 360 + bear

    deg = bear * math.pi / 180

    dx = dist * math.sin(deg)
    dy = dist * math.cos(deg)
    x = pnt.x() + dx
    y = pnt.y() + dy

    return QgsPointXY(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The result is the same:
[image]