# Splitting line with point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, point, vector, line, splitting

With two layers, one multiline and one point, I need to split lines who intersect point layer.

In example (image), the selected line is unique but I need 11 lines cut at point level.

[image]

How can I do this with QGIS?

Comment: You could try the SAGA algorithm Split Lines at Points in the processing toolbox and run it with Selected features only checkbox ticked for your line layer.

Comment: Have you checked [Splitting a line layer using another point layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/264773/63384)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using only QGIS native tools, you can convert the points to small, auxiliary lines, perpendicular to the line you want to split. Then use [Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines).

To create the auxiliary lines, use this expression with [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) on the line layer. Replace `point` (line 4) with the name of your point layer:

```
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach (
        aggregate( 
            'point', 
            'array_agg', 
            $geometry
        ),
        extend (
            make_line(
                line_interpolate_point( 
                    $geometry,
                    line_locate_point($geometry,@element)
                ),
            project (
                 line_interpolate_point( 
                    $geometry,
                    line_locate_point($geometry,@element)
                ),
                10,
                radians(
                    90+line_interpolate_angle( 
                        $geometry,
                        line_locate_point($geometry,@element)
            )))),
            10,
            0
)))
```

Use the newly created auxiliary lines to split the initial line into segments.

*Screenshot: the small red auxiliary lines are created (here: with geometry generator) on the line-layer, based on the points. As you see from the colors, the line is then split at these points:*

[image]

Comment: as mentioned in this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/475866/geometry-by-expression-does-not-work-after-intersection/ could I suggest an edit to change the `$geometry` in the `aggregate()` function to `geometry_n($geometry,1)` so that it works with multipoint layers? Also an alternative approach of using `overlay_nearest()` instead of `aggregate()` (with `limit:= -1` and some `max_distance` parameter)  so that it can work even if there is >1 feature in the line layer.

Comment: actually maybe it should be `if(is_multipart($geometry),geometry_n($geometry,1),$geometry))` because `geometry_n()` returns null if it's not multipart.

Comment: Great! Feel free to add this as an additional solution

Answer (score 9):

Let's assume there are two layers *'lines_test'* (blue) and *'points_test'* (orange), see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** By means of the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) with the following expression:

```
make_line($geometry, translate($geometry, 10, 10))
```

[image: window]

create tiny lines starting/ending at those points

[image: step_1]

On this step a smarter approach may be required, thus tiny lines *should not* overlap with initial lines. I would probably refer to these threads then: [Perpendicular lines on line using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380361/perpendicular-lines-on-line-using-qgis) and [Creating line segments at point coordinates in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311664/creating-line-segments-at-point-coordinates-in-qgis).

**Step 2.** Use the ["Split with lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) with the result from the *Step 1* and get the final output

[image: step_2]