# Splitting lines between points and changing color

Tags: qgis

I have got two layers;

1. road centrelines (lines)
2. points along those centrelines at random interval with two points close to each other determining a segment (points).

I am trying to change color of the lines that lie between two points. There are thousands of points and lines in the data so I can't do it manually. Is there any automatic command/plugin that can aid in minimising the this task?

Comment: What do you mean with *"two points close to each other"*, are they exactly in the same coordinates, if not it will be more difficult to find the segments division?

Comment: How were the points along centerlines created? How close are those points to the centerlines?

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/413121/88814