# Splitting line layer with point layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I created 1 connected road network without segments. In the image I selected the line to show that it is fully connected.

Now I want to split the line layer into segments at the points. does someone know how?

If I use SAGA Split lines at points I get the result shown in the second image.

UPDATE:
I fixed it myself by snapping the line on the points. This will create the correct segment.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to use the SAGA-tool `split lines at points`?

Comment: the saga tool does not work how I want it to work. I updated my question with the saga results in it

Comment: Please make sure you used the correct point layer.

Comment: I did checked it multiple times. But the line is splitting on certain intersection points from the line layer itself. I don't understand why because it should be 1 connected line layer.

Comment: Can you provide example data? can you provide a screenshot of the arguments you hand to the tool?

Comment: I updated the question. The arguments are in the 3th image. How do I share shapefiles with you?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the point layer from the already opened ones?

Comment: yes, but that is not the problem...

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to narrow down the error source, since the tool works flawlessly with my data. Have you tried with mockup data?

Comment: Can I send you my shapefiles? mabye you can reproduce the error. What is mockup data? I am glad you are willing to help.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GyOBuc3MBK_j4ZCXYUKp429-b-OORIiR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ax5w8I2SSOlNTURPFAl51aZBNuPplcOF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This question was asked before - see here for a solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413117/splitting-line-with-point-layer-in-qgis/413121#413121