# Connect touching lines by condition using expressions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, merge, qgis-expression

I have a polyline layer (Layer_A) in QGIS that represents entities (street crossings) that either consist of a single feature or are split into two or more features. The entities may also touch at their endpoints. I want to join the lines that belong to the same entity into one feature, but there is no attribute that I can use for that. So I need a geometry-based approach.

My current approach is the following:

1. Extract all *Layer_A* endpoints using **Extract specific vertices** tool and vertex indices `0,1`.
2. Extract all intermediate endpoints using **Extract by expression** tool with the following expression, where *Layer_B* is used to also exclude vertices where two Layer_A entities touch each other, as in that case they always touch *Layer_B*:

```
array_length(
  overlay_touches(
    'Layer_A',
    $geometry
  )
) > 1

AND

array_length(
  overlay_touches(
    'Layer_B',
    $geometry
  )
) = 0
```

This gives the following result (Layer_A purple, Layer_B green):

[image: Sample data screenshot]

This shows that two Layer_A entities consist of two separate lines. The set of purple lines is supposed to be four entities (crossings) here. So I can't use **Dissolve** with the `Keep disjoint features separate` option.

I now want to iterate over the new point layer and join the lines together that touch the respective point, so that I have a single line for each entity in the end.

Here's the merging condition: *Merge all features from Layer A (crossings) at their touching start/end points, except when they touch at least one feature from Layer_B (here: sidewalks) at this respective start/end point.*

I look for solutions using geometry expressions either as an extension of my approach - or as a completely different solution.

[Layer_A (crossings) sample data](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1EtH) (Overpass query, export e.g. as GeoJSON)

[Layer_B (sidewalks) sample data](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1EtE) (Overpass query, export e.g. as GeoJSON)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdissolve) with the option `Keep disjoint features separate` activated.
2. Get the points where layer A touches layer B, e.g. using [`overlay_touches()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-touches).
3. Split lines of layer A at these points using [this approach](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/413121/88814).

Comment: Thank you. I tested it [using this model](https://nextcloud.stadtkreation.de/index.php/s/42gpNq4mWwMtGDj) (still incomplete). I get an error for "Geometry by expression": *Error encountered while running Geometry by expression: Evaluation error: Cannot convert to geometry*.

Comment: Maybe there's a difference when using the expression here and not within the Geometry generator?

Comment: It turned out that I didn't even need the `Geometry by expression` step and could use `Split with lines` for Layer_B in the end. Nevertheless, your solution seems to be highly valuable for other cases where Layer_B does not exist and the conditions require an approach based on vertices.